# Repeated Rake Task Using Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am currently using the delayed_job gem and I was wondering how to run a rake task every 5 minutes.

I want to run "rake ts:reindex RAILS_ENV=production" every 5 minutes but I'm not sure where to start. I really don't have much more I can say about this because I am VERY inexperienced in this area of rails development.

Comment: all the answers were great below but I ended up going with the whenever gem to keep everything tied together within my rails program. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Whenever gem to schedule your reindexing rake task or any other rake task to run every 5 minutes.

Its makes it very easy to create Cron jobs like these

Comment: What if you don't want to use rake so that you can avoid rails starting up every time you need to run a DJ?

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest using thinking sphinx reindexing every 5 minutes. If you really want that put something like this into your /etc/crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * your_username cd /path/to/rails/root && rake ts:reindex RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 1):

Thinking Sphinx (assuming you're using it due to the ts:reindex mention) has internal hooks to use delayed job for indexing. Have you taken a look at [delayed delta indexing](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/deltas.html)? You will probably end up using the crontab to actually run the periodic delta reindex as Eimantas mentioned.

Comment: But add delta indexing costs near 50 dollars in heroku!

Comment: Well, this answer is 5 years old, but I don't use or recommend Heroku for reasons like that.